# A closed trajectory of a positively charged test particle in a two source charge electric field

Tags: electrostatics

We have two fixed point charges in space, the charges be **+Q** and **-q**. Is it possible to find a location and velocity of release of a point charge **+q'** such that the **+q'** charge doesn't eventually fall into the **-q** charge ?
Well, if we didn't had that extra **+Q** charge then for any non-zero velocity of release, the **+q'** charge would follow a conic section trajectory with **-q** at the focus. But, what happens when we have that extra **+Q** ?

Comment: Boldface usually indicates vectors. Charge is not a vector quantity.

Answer (score 1):

No we cannot (Unless you allows $\textbf{+Q}$ to go to $\infty$). This is pretty straight forward if you just think about the field lines, they will always go from the positive charge to the negative one. Your free charge (if it positive) will always travel with the Field lines and as a result will always collide with $\textbf{-q}$.

Comment: Imagine -q be kept at x = -1 and +Q be kept at x = +1 now if the charge is released with 0 velocity at a point x > +1 where do you think the charge will go?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer:

Imagine -q be kept at x = -1 and +Q be kept at x = +1 now if the charge is released with 0 velocity at a point x > +1 where do you think the charge will go?

Well you can think that it will remain on x-axis and never go to -q, but what about the uncertainity principle? How can you place it exactly on the x-axis?